# SQL: Select all distinct and pick the row that has the max value in another column

Tags: mysql, groupwise-maximum

```
| nid | vid | max_score |
|-----+-----+-----------|
|  1  |  1  |     1     |
|-----+-----+-----------|
|  1  |  2  |     1     |
|-----+-----+-----------|
|  2  |  1  |     1     |
|-----+-----+-----------|
|  2  |  2  |     2     |
-------------------------
```

I would like to select only the distinct nid, but also only take the row where the vid is the highest.

So the result here would give me

1, 2, 1

2, 2, 2

Comment: Luckily, this question is asked (and answered) almost every single day in SO.

Comment: `SELECT nid, MAX(vid) vid,max_score  FROM table GROUP BY nid`

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid No. Because, presumably, BobbyS also wants the corresponding max_score

Comment: @ChrisHayes. The SQL tag itself explains why.

Comment: @BobbyS All answers provided so far are wrong - which is depressing. Do we really have to go over this one again?

Comment: Yes, the inclusion of the term 'exclusively' is silly. Anyone asking such a question is unlikely to know (or care) whether or not the solution relies upon a non-standard extension! Maybe I'll edit it...

Comment: I agree with your logic, but not your conclusion, because in practice answers for one RDBMS are rarely applicable to another.